# Fullcalendar - Quarter and Year View

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a requirement to show the quarter and year view with vertical scroll rather than scrolling horizontally. Need to see the dates on the left axis and scroll down vertically to see all the events down the page as we do in normal calendars, to see the months one after the other. Do we have some view like :  initialView: 'dayGridMonth' or initialView: 'dayGridQuarter'

Comment: please attach image for ref if possible or you can add some dummy image for ref....to check ...what is your req

Comment: dayGridMonth exists yes - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/month-view . There is nothing for a quarter, though. As I think you've already worked out, the best you can do for that is use the Timeline view, which does what you want but shows horizontally. For now you'll probably have to live with that slight disadvantage compared to your exact requirement. I'm sure your users will get used to it.

Comment: For reference, all the available views currently are documented at https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc. You're welcome to try and write your own [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) of course, or you can vote on / create a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to try and get the fullCalendar project to implement the exact thing you're looking for.